# Como o telegram e o facebook messenger limpam as notificações nos dispositivos?

Tags: ios, api, push-notification

Quando você recebe uma notificação pelo Telegram ou Facebook Messenger em vários dispositivos, se você ler a mensagem em um deles nos outros a notificação é removida.

Como isso acontece?

PS: isso acontece mesmo se o aplicativo não estiver rodando no celular.

Comment: foi mal cara.. força do habito, nem percebi que estava no em português.

Comment: Não sou desenvolvedor mobile, mas acredito que os aplicativos ficam checando em segundo plano/thread a cada x segundos se a mensagem/ação referente aquela notificação já foi vista ou realizada, se sim, ele remove...

Comment: @HérculesMoreira: Não, isso não faz sentido, pq isso acontece com plataformas diferentes.. android, desktop e ios.. se vc viu em uma, nas outras ele é marcado como lido.

Comment: Sem problemas Raphael. Reverti meu voto para fechar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665634/how-to-clear-a-notification-in-android

Comment: Não.. isso acontece mesmo se o aplicativo não estiver rodando.

Comment: Não é possível enviar um "push" para remover a notificação anterior? :S

Answer (score 0):

Respondido.

No caso do iOS vc tem que enviar o payload da notificação sem o alert e com badge = 0, dessa forma ela vai cancelar as notificações.

`{"aps":{"badge":0}}`

Mas pra isso dar certo a opção expiry do payload das notificações tem que ser maior que 0.